# sony xperia z5 camera 60 fps

Tags: sony, android-camera2, sony-xperia

We work with a Sony Xperia Z5 device and have encountered difficulties retrieving a 60fps video stream (VGA or HD) from the front (and back) camera using Android APIs.  We don't use the media recorder, we want to do live image processing and therefore don't need to save the images. We used the getHighSpeedVideoFpsRanges() Method but didn't get any results. This is somehow a strange behaviour. It would be great to use the front camera for this.
Is there any other way to access the camera via the Android APIs with 60fps (or more)? 
Are there other (Sony) devices that allow retrieving 60fps streams for third party apps via the Android APIs?
[Empty result - getHighSpeedVideoFpsRanges()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBedJ.png)

Comment: Have you upgraded the OS from the original Lollipop 5.1.1?

Comment: Yes. We have tried it with Android 6.0.1 and Android 7.0. Both with the same results.

Comment: From you description, it is not clear whether the difficulties are device-specific, or if Z5 is the single device you have to develop this feature. In the latter case, maybe the problem is with your code. If you post it here, somebody may find a bug in your code.

Comment: We have also tested it with a Google Nexus 5x and it worked as we got results. Therefore we are very curios why it does not work with the Z5 (and probably other sony devices too) because the camera theoretically should be capable of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the internet forums, e.g. [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/4c520n/psa_sony_xperia_z5_on_marshmallow_now_has_usable/) or [Xperia Support](https://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Software-Updates/Camera2-API/td-p/974742), this device does not have full camera2 implementation. It seems that Sony only provides [legacy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL) camera2 hardware level.

In some cases, you can achieve more through the *deprecated* [hardware.Camera](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) API. I am not sure if specifically for Sony Xperia Z5, it is possible to receive reliable 60 fps video stream with the old API, but the big question is whether it is worthwhile to invest in such R&D effort.